# Direct download for free products in shopify store

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-template, digital-downloads

Currently, I have some free products over my Shopify site and users are able to download them but they have to go through Checkout. I am looking for a solution where users can direct download free products.

[Here is link to free products page:](https://jaycactus.com/collections/frontpage)

There is a website that currently does this but I want to know how they are doing this. Below is a look at them;
[Refrence site:](https://cymatics.fm/pages/free-download-vault)

Comment: They just add the email capturing form and create a separate thank you page where a zip file is added, so basically, there is no Shopify product on reference during the download process.

Comment: @Onkar Can you please write some details?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this you can add a download button on any page [Adding a download link to Shopify](https://help.groupthought.com/article/728-how-to-add-a-pdf-download-on-a-product-page)